# MySQL query to exclude a range of dates not working

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I have a dataset that includes the booking_date field stored as 2021-08-31.  I need to run a query that excludes all dates further forward than a specific range ie today +7.

Using:

```
SELECT *
FROM work_jobs
WHERE (cast(booking_date as date)  NOT BETWEEN DATE_ADD(cast(NOW() as date), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()) AND job_closed = 0 ORDER BY booking_date ASC;
```

does not work.  The full dataset with dates in the future is returned.

Any suggestions?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: booking_date is a VARCHAR in the db.

Comment: Does not work is not a useful error description.

Comment: If booking_date is a  varchar (which is a bad decision by the way) you should use str_to_date(booking_date, '%Y-%m-%d') and not cast

Comment: Thanks I'll try that... I inherited this schema and know that I need to make quite a few changes.

Comment: SELECT *
 FROM work_jobs
 WHERE (str_to_date(booking_date, '%Y-%m-%d')  NOT BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()) AND job_closed = 0 ORDER BY booking_date ASC;

Still returns the full dataset....

Comment: Your second date is before the first date. Try to swap them

Comment: Why are using between if you want to exclude anything earlier than a particular date?   Assuming you fix the order of arguments for your between and convert the date properly  this would exclude today and tomorrow but would include the day after that.   Why not just `str_to_date(booking_date, '%Y-%m-%d') < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much - that worked.

WHERE (str_to_date(booking_date, '%Y-%m-%d') < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()) AND job_closed = pJobClosed ORDER BY booking_date ASC;

I have always struggled with dates :). All the best; stay safe.